# How to implement element ordering accross two different models in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I've got these `Car` and `Bike` models I can't modify.

They may need to be linked to a `Ferry` model which I can modify. I want to implement ordering of these elements of two different models in the database and I want to avoid using Generic Foreign Keys.

So far this is what I've come up with:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    pass
    
class Bike(models.Model):
    pass
    
class Ferry(models.Model):
    pass
    
class Lot(models.Model):
    position = SmallInteger()
    car = models.ForeignKey(to=Car, null=True, related_name="ferries")
    bike = models.ForeignKey(to=Bike, null=True, related_name="ferries")
    ferry = models.ForeignKey(to=Ferry, null=False, related_name="load")
```

Now my goal is to be able to access directly all the elements of a particular `Ferry` – be they cars or bikes – ordered by position, and all the ferries (in the context of ferry travel bookings there may be several) of a particular car or bike:

```
some_ferry.load.all().order_by("position")
some_car.ferries.all()
```

How do I create these relations, including a sort of combination of (`Car` + `Bike`)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to put ordering on the `Lot` table by position?

Comment: Exactly, each `Car` and `Bike` on a ferry should have a `position` number by which they can be ordered. `Lot` is the intermediary table which carries that position, it's what I've come up with but it doesn't necessarily have to be like that.

Comment: Do each Lot may have both, a Car and a Bike, or do one excludes the other?

Comment: It is exclusive. Also, it cannot be empty (maybe `Lot` wasn't a good pick for the class name, I really mean the scalar position of the vehicle in a row): I mean to make sure of that in each method creating a `Lot`. I do that in order to avoid Generic Foreign Keys.

Answer (score 0):

So you can put ordering on the table or as you make a query and you can use django's `__` notation to use fields on related objects ([more here](https://www.dev2qa.com/what-does-double-underscore-__-means-in-django-model-queryset-objects-filter-method/))

For example;

```py
class Car(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        """
        Metadata
        """
        ordering = ('ferries__position', )
    
class Bike(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        """
        Metadata
        """
        ordering = ('ferries__position', )
    
class Ferry(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        """
        Metadata
        """
        ordering = ('load__position', )
    
class Lot(models.Model):
    position = SmallInteger()
    car = models.ForeignKey(to=Car, null=True, related_name="ferries")
    bike = models.ForeignKey(to=Bike, null=True, related_name="ferries")
    ferry = models.ForeignKey(to=Ferry, null=False, related_name="load")

    class Meta:
        """
        Metadata
        """
        ordering = ('position', )
```

Or in your queries it might be `Bike.objects.all().order_by('ferries__position')`

If you define the ordering in the model meta, then that'll be the default ordering for all queries on that model so you don't then have to worry about it when you're making queries or looking at admin etc.

Comment: Ok this does help a lot. Now `some_ferry.load.all()` will get me `Lot` objects effectively ordered by their positions. My goal now is that the query wouldn't return the `Lot` objects but either the `Car` or the `Bike` objects they contain (and reciprocally). Can it do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way you can achieve what you want without using Generic Foreign Key, since the relationship you envision does not exist in Django (and, actually, is not a nicely normalized relational database pattern. Other database paradigms, such as OODB and GraphDB do include this pattern).

What you can do is to define a method on class `Ferry` that would query for all instances of Cars and  Bikes and join them in a single resultset.

Another option is to use library [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which would allow you to define a model, let's say, `Transportation`, that would act as some sort of virtual model, and you can define models `Bike` and `Car` as subclasses of it. With this solution, you can create a foreign key on `Lot` pointing to `Transportation`, and you can query for `Bike`, `Car`, or the generic `Transportation` instances.